# Coding an email that Siri and Google Now will pick up Schema.org markup from?

Tags: schema.org, google-schemas, google-now, siri, cortana

Microsoft have provided some interesting documentation on passing data to Cortana, in this example it is a flight schedule using [Schema.org](http://schema.org/): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632191.aspx

Does anyone know if the same method is true for iOS and Android platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just reviewed the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632191.aspx), you've posted. Yes, you can integrate with Google Now in a similar way. You can find the supported Google Now schemas in the link below. You'll find microdata/json examples:

https://developers.google.com/schemas/now/cards

You can start testing Gmail Schemas with the below Apps Script Quickstart tutorial with your personal Gmail account. When the From: and To: fields match each other, actions will get displayed. However, if you try to send to another Gmail account, actions will not appear.

https://developers.google.com/schemas/tutorials/apps-script-tutorial

Note, if you simply copy and paste the examples in Apps Script, please use a current date in order to trigger a Now card. For example today's date:

```
"departureTime": "2015-06-22T20:15:00-08:00"

"arrivalTime": "2015-06-22T23:30:00-05:00"
```

If you plan to use Gmail Schemas for your users/customers, you'll have to [register](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1PA-vjjk3yJF7MLPOVKbIz3MBfhyma2obS8NIZ0JYx8I/viewform?pli=1). You can find details on how to register at the link below:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google

Note, you'll have to be within their [guidelines](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google#registration_guidelines) and you will have to provide a sample email during the registration process.

Hope this points you to the right direction.

Comment: This is excellent, thanks!  Anyone have any instruction on Siri - this info seems to be non-existent.

Comment: @JoelBondoux glad the info was helpful. If this was the answer you were looking for, please submit my response as the "answer."

Comment: that's the Siri documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirieventsuggestionsmarkup/